# Haskell, how to check for a palindrom

Tags: function, haskell

I have a small question.  How could I extend my function to return `True` even if a character is a capital letter or not.

My function works for Strings in lists:

```
f1 w = w == reverse w

Test:
*Main> let test = ["Boob"]
*Main> f1 test
True

*Main> let test2 = "Boob"
*Main> f1 test2
False
```

regards,

martin

Comment: Check out [`Data.Char`](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/libraries/base/Data-Char.html). There are functions regarding the case that could be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

f1 :: String -> Bool
f1 w = w == reverse w

f2 :: String -> Bool
f2 str = f1 $ map toLower str
```

but what I would suggest is using good names for your functions

```
testPalindrome = f1
ignoreCase = map toLower
```

then

```
testPalindrome' = testPalindrome . ignoreCase
```

### Update:

The `.` is concatenation of functions:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(g . f) x = g (f x)


     f
 A -----> B
  \       |
   \      |
g.f \     |g
     \    |
      V   V
        C
```

### Update2

@dfeuer mentioned in the comments a very elegant solution

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.Char (toLower)

(=~=) :: String -> String -> Bool
-- | Equivalence of Strings, by ignoring the case
(=~=) = (==) `on` toLower

testPalindrome :: String -> Bool
testPalindrome w = w =~= reverse w
```

The function `on` (used infix with backtick syntax) takes a function `(==)` and a "modifier-function" `toLower` and applies it to the arguments of that function.

```
(f `on` g) x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

this is especially useful with binary operators like `(==)`, `(<)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What exactly is the dot-operation? Does the dot binds the two functions like in imperative languages?

Comment: @MartinM No (if I'm understanding you correctly), the dot is function composition. It's defined as `(f . g) x = f (g x)`

Comment: Yes, but I realized that yours is more efficient for this purpose, because mine smashes case twice!